# setValue on dynamic angular material 'select' tag does not work

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a 'mat-select' tag with dynamic options(which are loaded with http).

```html
    <mat-select placeholder="Parent" formControlName="ParentId">
       <mat-option value="0">Without Parent</mat-option>
       <mat-option [value]="item.id" *ngFor="let item of menuItems">{{item.title}}</mat-option>
     </mat-select>
```

After fetching menuItems, I `setValue` the form:

```js
  async loadFormData() {
    this.menuItems = await this.menuService.getMenuItems();

    if (this.itemId) {
      let item = await this.menuService.getMenuItem(this.itemId);
      this.addMenuItemForm.setValue({ParentId: 13});
    }
  }
```

but it does not work. the same code works perfectly with static options.

Comment: An option with id=13 exists in my data

Answer (score 0):

`setvalue` is only for controls. use `patchvalue` for form. 
reference: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value

Comment: really you can use setValue to give value to a FormGroup, but you need give value to all the constrols of the group, so, another way can be `this.addMenuItemForm.setValue({...this.addMenuItemForm.value,ParentId:13})`

Comment: didn't know that. but this is some extracode. `patchvalue` looks cleaner and gets the job done.